# How to transform TypeScript code below to JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
function PrivateRoute({ children } : any ) {
    const accessToken = false;
    const loading = false;
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const fromLocation = (location.state as any)?.from;
    const previousLocation = location.state ? fromLocation : { pathname: '/login' };
```

How to transform two lines of code with 'any' keyword to javascript code?

Comment: Just remove the type annotations?

Comment: You could also run it through the TypeScript compiler to get JavaScript!

Comment: An upvote would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove '`: any`' and '`as any`' as JavaScript doesn't have data type hints.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the typings. The ':any'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function PrivateRoute(_a) {
    var _b;
    var children = _a.children;
    var accessToken = false;
    var loading = false;
    var navigate = useNavigate();
    var location = useLocation();
    var fromLocation = (_b = location.state) === null || _b === void 0 ? void 0 : _b.from;
    var previousLocation = location.state ? fromLocation : { pathname: '/login' };
}
```